# Is it possible to gray out a map except for some area?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I’ve found a page making a simulation of such behavior:  [Link](http://maps.vasile.ch/geomask/)     (which is acceptable solution for me), but when I put my own coordinates to the example – it doesn’t work simply. Example:

```
var myPoints = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.992148, 20.116691),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.958793, 20.099713),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.961392, 20.099613),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.967183, 20.101399),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.967362, 20.099692),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.966189, 20.097904),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.965657, 20.096844),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.964799, 20.095155),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.969056, 20.092539),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.978430, 20.096734),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.992148, 20.116691)
];
var oldPoints = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.939952, 20.089703),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.936804, 20.102749),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.938516, 20.117512),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.937687, 20.132961),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.941941, 20.145321),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.963368, 20.140686),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.974354, 20.099745),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.958841, 20.080090),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.939952, 20.089703)
];
```

Working demo:

```
var polygonMask = new google.maps.Polygon({
  map:map,
  strokeColor: '#000000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#CACACA',
  fillOpacity: 0.7,
  paths: [[new google.maps.LatLng(49.441831, 19.170290),
           new google.maps.LatLng(50.501727, 19.170290),
           new google.maps.LatLng(50.501727, 20.962435),
           new google.maps.LatLng(49.441831, 20.962435),
           new google.maps.LatLng(49.441831, 19.170290)],
          oldPoints                                         <--
  ]
});
```

When I switch “oldPoints” to “myPoints” – it doesn’t work, meaning everything is grayed out. Do you know if should be there any concrete order of those points or why myPoints doesn’t work? I couldn’t find any information about that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hole" needs to wind in the opposite direction of the outer boundary.

code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var polygonMask = new google.maps.Polygon({
        map: map,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#CACACA',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        paths: [
            [new google.maps.LatLng(49.441831, 19.170290),
            new google.maps.LatLng(50.501727, 19.170290),
            new google.maps.LatLng(50.501727, 20.962435),
            new google.maps.LatLng(49.441831, 20.962435),
            new google.maps.LatLng(49.441831, 19.170290)],
            revPoints
        ]
    });
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < polygonMask.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        bounds.extend(polygonMask.getPath().getAt(i));
    }
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
    
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var geocoder;
var map;
var myPoints = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.992148, 20.116691),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.958793, 20.099713),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.961392, 20.099613),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.967183, 20.101399),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.967362, 20.099692),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.966189, 20.097904),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.965657, 20.096844),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.964799, 20.095155),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.969056, 20.092539),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.978430, 20.096734),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.992148, 20.116691)
];
var oldPoints = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.939952, 20.089703),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.936804, 20.102749),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.938516, 20.117512),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.937687, 20.132961),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.941941, 20.145321),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.963368, 20.140686),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.974354, 20.099745),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.958841, 20.080090),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.939952, 20.089703)
];

var revPoints =[];
for (var i=1;i<=myPoints.length;i++) {
    revPoints.push(myPoints[myPoints.length-i]);
}
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: yes, you're right, it was that reason, but simpler solution is to change an order of outer boundary's points - only 4 points to swap :). Thanks a lot for your time and willing to help. Best Regards from Poland :)

Comment: However, if you want to cover the whole world you need more than 4 points.